# Crude palm oil DOBI analysis

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, bond, kinetics, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I'm performing Crude Palm Oil DOBI spectrum analysis using uv-1900i UV-VIS spectrophotometer at a range of 269nm and 446nm but it's only giving peak absorbance at 446nm but no reading at 269nm,what could be the problem? Please note that I took 0.4g of CPO and dissolved to 100ml mark volumetric flask using iso-octane, which was also used as the blank (iso-octane)

Comment: What is your cuvet material?